# How to add an array elements in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am working with arrays this time and I want to add elements. Whenever a user adds some value in the array I want it to be added to the previous value and give me the total value.

```
struct KeyValues{
    var category:String!
    var amount:String!  
}

var arrExpense = [KeyValues]()
```

In my case, I am adding values to the amount variable. I want the sum of all the values user has added to the amount values. How can I achieve that in swift. Do I need to use loop or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **never** declare a struct member as implicit unwrapped optional. If it's supposed to be optional declare it as regular optional (`?`)

Second of all if a value won't change (maybe `category`) declare it as constant (`let`)

You can sum up the values with `compactMap` and `reduce`

```
struct KeyValues {
    let category : String
    var amount : String
}


let sum = arrExpense.compactMap{Int($0.amount)}.reduce(0, +)
```

`compactMap` is necessary to filter the strings which cannot be converted to `Int`. Consider to use a numeric type for `amount`

Comment: I would declare both properties as constants even if the amount may change. If OP needs to change it all he needs is to create a new object.

Answer (score -1):

see this [switf arrays article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array)

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,5]

numbers.append(6)        // [1,2,3,5,6]
numbers.insert(4, at: 3) // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
numbers.remove(at: 1)    // [1,3,4,5,6]
numbers.removeLast()     // [1,3,4,5]

let total = numbers.reduce(0, +)  // 0 = starting point, + = operation
// 0 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 13
```

Comment: you have answered a different  (and simpler) question